# Dynamic TypeScript imports without using Promises

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

I have this situation. The reason they are dynamic is to prevent loading 10x the amount of code that I need to load to do a certain command-line task.

```
if (diagnostics) {
  require('./lib/cli-commands/run-diagnostics').run(sumanOpts);
}
else if (script) {
  require('./lib/cli-commands/run-scripts').run(sumanConfig, sumanOpts);
}
else if (tscMultiWatch) {
  require('./lib/cli-commands/run-tscmultiwatch').run(sumanOpts);
}
else if (repair) {
  require('./lib/cli-commands/run-repair').run(sumanOpts);
}
else if (postinstall) {
  require('./lib/cli-commands/postinstall').run(sumanOpts);
}
else{
  // etc etc
}
```

if I try a dynamic loading import call, I get this:

[image]

It's clearly going to return a `Promise` not the `module.exports` value.

*Is there a way to use dynamic import syntax without asynchronous loading or no?*

Comment: Basically I am looking for "synchronous dynamic imports" instead of "asynchronous dynamic imports"

Comment: Have you observed that there actually is a performance hit from just including all of them?

Comment: @JLRishe there will be a hit, however small, it will load a lot of files, and potentially log things that I don't want to be logged, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to add to Unional's correct answer, it is very easy to work with the `Promise` returning dynamic import syntax.

```
(async function () {
  if (diagnostics) {
    const run = await import('./lib/cli-commands/run-diagnostics');
    run(sumanOpts);
  }
  else if (script) {
    const run = await import('./lib/cli-commands/run-scripts');
    run(sumanConfig, sumanOpts);
  }
}());
```

Note that if you are using `--module commonjs` modules then it is likely best to stick to require. However, the above is perfect for `--module amd`, `--module system`, and of course `--module esnext`.

Comment: yeah I frankly don't see why supporting a dynamic *synchronous* import would not be possible, but I guess it's a restriction of ES that TS has to adhere to

Comment: Yes but it is a good restriction, I don't see a need for dynamic synchronous import. I would rather see a top level `await` construct. But again, runtimes can add extra features, like Node adds require, so there isn't a problem.

Comment: it is not working for me.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60056219/how-to-use-dynamic-import-in-typescript-with-webpack-application

Comment: @kumaresan_sd  If you read the question asked here, you will see that it is different from the question you asked in your post.  I read your post, and you have a different and unrelated issue. I would be happy to help you with that, but it's rather  unhelpful to downvote an answer to a largely unrelated question that was accepted as working  to get help with your own especially since you didn't read  the question here carefully.  Your problem is that you're loading from the wrong path and getting a 404. That's a different problem.

Answer (score 3):

By the nature of dynamic import, it is asynchronous.

`require()` is synchronous because it lives on the server side. You can read a file synchronously using (for example) `fs.readFileSync()`.

For the new dynamic import, it is designed to work on the client side so there will be an ajax request back to the server to perform the import.

Thus it has to be asynchronous.

Comment: seems like it, if I get no further info, will have to accept this answer

Comment: Why do you don't want it to be asynchronous? Are you not happy with the Promise syntax or....?

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote **import-sync** which may help with this use case.

- npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-sync
- github: https://github.com/nktnet1/import-sync

The library is a wrapper around [esm](https://github.com/standard-things/esm) and enables ESM imports from both ES6 and CJS-based NodeJS projects.

I haven't experimented extensively with TS dynamic imports, but from what I've tried/tested, it does run with `ts-node`.

For example,

```js
// const importSync = require('import-sync');
import importSync from 'import-sync';

if (diagnostics) {
  importSync('./lib/cli-commands/run-diagnostics').run(sumanOpts);
}
else if (script) {
  importSync('./lib/cli-commands/run-scripts').run(sumanConfig, sumanOpts);
}
else if (tscMultiWatch) {
  importSync('./lib/cli-commands/run-tscmultiwatch').run(sumanOpts);
}
else if (repair) {
  importSync('./lib/cli-commands/run-repair').run(sumanOpts);
}
else if (postinstall) {
  importSync('./lib/cli-commands/postinstall').run(sumanOpts);
}
else{
  // etc etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Asynchronous-only dynamic `import()` is [an ECMAScript feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import), and the trend in TypeScript evolution is to stick to ECMAScript where possible.
2. TypeScript can be configured to output JS in different ways and accommodate different module systems. It’s true that one of those options is to transpile your TS project all into a single JS file that uses AMD, in which case TypeScript converts all of your imports into synchronous `require()`s, meaning you *could* have a synchronous `import()` function. However, that’s only *one* of all possible transpilation targets. You can see that it’s understandable if TypeScript doesn’t want to introduce a new way of `import()`—incompatible with ECMAScript!—as a special case for just one possible transpilation mode.