# How to use dynamic import in typescript with webpack application

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack-4, dynamic-import

I have import some of my modules dynamically based on button click, i have used like below"

```js
import { Button } from '@syncfusion/ej2-buttons';

// Initialize Button component.
let button: Button = new Button({ content: 'Button' });

// Render initialized Button.
button.appendTo('#element');

document.getElementById('element').addEventListener("click", function(){
  check();
});

async function check() {
import("@syncfusion/ej2-grids").then((Grid) => {
  debugger
  console.log(Grid);
});
}
```

> my webpack config file:

```js
const path = require("path");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    "src/app/bundle": "./src/app/index.ts"
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: "/js/",
    filename: "src/app/bundle.js"
  },
  devtool: "none",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
  }
};
```

when i compile and run my application it throws below error

> What is the current behavior?

Throws below error
[image: error message]

If the current behavior is a bug, please provide the steps to reproduce.

```
clone sample - https://github.com/kumaresan-subramani/dynamic-import/blob/master/webpack.config.js
run npm i
gulp compile
gulp start
```

Then click button in browser, you will see reported error in my console.

> What is the expected behavior?

Dynamic module should load properly

> Other relevant information:

```
"typescript": "3.7.5",
"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
"webpack": "^4.29.6",
"webpack-cli": "*",
"webpack-stream": "^5.2.1"
Node.js version: 10.15.1
Operating System: windows 10
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400982/error-loading-chunk-0-failed-webpack-tries-to-load-0-js  similar issues

Answer (score -2):

The whole logic seems weird for me.
If you use a module just import it and then use it under certain conditions or after event is triggered